# Extract Data from file using python

Tags: python, text, format

**Input File:**

```
["abc","on time","date","<a href='link'>11111</a>","time","2","2"],

["abc","on time","date","<a href='link'>11111</a>","time","2","6"],

["abc","on time","date","<a href='link'>11111</a>","time","2","9"],

["abc","on time","date","<a href='link'>11111</a>","time","2","0"],

["abc","on time","date","<a href='link'>11111</a>","time","2","5"]
```

**output to be needed:**

```
abc,on time,date,<a href='link'>11111</a>,time,2,2

abc,on time,date,<a href='link'>11111</a>,time,2,6

abc,on time,date,<a href='link'>11111</a>,time,2,9

abc,on time,date,<a href='link'>11111</a>,time,2,0

abc,on time,date,<a href='link'>11111</a>,time,2,5
```

**Code tried:**

```
import sys
import re

Lines = [Line.strip() for Line in open (sys.argv[1],'r').readlines()]



for EachLine in Lines:
    Parts = EachLine.split(",")
    for EachPart in Parts:

        EachPart = re.sub(r'[', '', EachPart)
        EachPart = re.sub(r']', '', EachPart)
print ' '.join(Parts)
```

Can anyone help me on this?? I am not getting what i desired. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just want to print it that format or save it in a file?

Comment: anything is fine... i could redirect the output to a file also.

Comment: What are you getting, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your initial solution to

```
import sys
import re

Lines = [Line.strip() for Line in open (sys.argv[1],'r').readlines()]

for EachLine in Lines:
    matches = re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"',EachLine)
    print ','.join(matches)
```

My approach is to use regex to get all string in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).

```
with open('a.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace(',\n', '\n').strip() # remove if there is `,` at the end
        if line:                                 # to tackle with empty lines
            print(','.join(eval(line.strip())))
```

### Input:

```
["abc","on time","date","<a href='link'>11111</a>","time","2","2"],

["abc","on time","date","<a href='link'>11111</a>","time","2","6"],

["abc","on time","date","<a href='link'>11111</a>","time","2","9"],

["abc","on time","date","<a href='link'>11111</a>","time","2","0"],

["abc","on time","date","<a href='link'>11111</a>","time","2","5"]
```

### Output:

```
abc,on time,date,<a href='link'>11111</a>,time,2,2
abc,on time,date,<a href='link'>11111</a>,time,2,6
abc,on time,date,<a href='link'>11111</a>,time,2,9
abc,on time,date,<a href='link'>11111</a>,time,2,0
abc,on time,date,<a href='link'>11111</a>,time,2,5
```

Comment: i am getting the desired output, but having an error:  print(','.join(eval(line.strip())))
  File "<string>", line 1
    ]
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @blackfury It works on my machine, can you check your input text file again and see if it is same with the original post? You can also print the last line in the for loop before it gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

Another option without using regex is:

```
for line in lines:
  formatted = ','.join(line).replace('"', '')
  print(formatted)
```